# How can display datagridview content to CrystalReport using MySql database

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports-2008

1. I'm using Visual Studio 2013
2. MySql Database

I've got a problem where it ask for the user and password every time click the report. Please Help

Comment: I don't know about Vb.net structure for Crystal Reports but you need to `verify database`..

Comment: why!!! ok thanks for your info